# How do I save PKDrawing in Swift with white background

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, pencilkit

I am using `PencilKit` framework to capture a user's drawing and save it.

I want to save a user input drawing with a white background. The image should look like this, where the canvas background I have is white.

[image]

I use the `UIImage` api from `drawing.image(from: bounds, scale: 1.0)` and save it. On saving the image, I get the following instead

[image]

It seems the background has been removed, although I want it kept. I want to later later convert the image into pixel values where white = 255 and black = 0 intensity.

How do I do this with Swift?

Thank you all for your guidance and help.

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of saving a `PKDrawing` object with `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: Hi I have not heard of NSKeyArchiver as I am new to Swift. Could you elaborate on how to do so?

Comment: I managed to solve it by overlaying the original image with a white UIImage background!